# Pyramid array builder

Tags: ascii-art, typescript

I'm developing, just for fun and learning, a TypeScript Class that creates an `Array<Array<string>>` that represents a pyramid. So, for `length = 5` the array would look like :

```
[
  ['X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X'],
  ['X', '0', '0', '0', 'X'],
  ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
]
```

The class constructor can take a few arguments:

1. The final array.
2. The length (width) of the pyramid, the "blank" String and the "piece" string

My implementation looks like:

[**`PLUNKER`**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DdMafAHTfV67yYmmEZTk?p=preview)

```
interface IPiramide {
    array?          : Array<Array<string>>,
    private blanco? :         string = 'X',
    private trozo?  :         string = 'O'
}

class Piramide implements IPiramide {

  constructor(piramide : IPiramide = {blanco : 'X', trozo : '0', ancho : 0}){

    this.blanco = piramide.blanco;
    this.trozo = piramide.trozo;

        if(piramide.array){
            this.array = piramide.array;
        }
        else if(piramide.ancho){
            this.build(piramide.ancho);
        }

    }

    static getInstance(ancho : number, blanco : string, trozo : string, inverse ? : boolean) : Piramide {
        return new Piramide({blanco, trozo}).build(ancho, inverse);
    }

    private build (ancho : number, inverse? : boolean = false) {
        this.array = [];
        let numberCount = ancho % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 1;
        let middle = Math.floor(ancho / 2);

        while (numberCount != ancho + 2){
            this.array.push(Array.from({length : ancho}, (el, idx)=>{
                let range = (ancho - numberCount)/2;
                return (idx < range || idx > ancho - range - 1) 
                  ? this.blanco 
                  : this.trozo;
            }));
            numberCount += 2;
        }
        inverse 
          ? this.array = this.array.map((el, idx, arr)=>arr[arr.length - idx - 1]) 
          : this.array;
        return this;
    }

    public getArray (){
        return this.array;
    }

    public getTrozo() {
      return this.array[Math.floor(this.array.length/2)][Math.floor(this.ancho/2)];
    }

    public getBlanco(){
      if(this.array.length){
        return this.array[1][0];
      }
      return null;
    }

    public getAncho(){
      return this.array[0].length;
    }

    public getAlto(){
      return this.array.length;
    }

    toString(){
        return this.array.map( el=> el.join(' ')).join('\n');
    }

    isConcatenable (piramide : Piramide) : boolean {
      console.log('isConcat', this);
      return this.getAlto() == piramide.getAlto();
    }

    reverse() : Piramide{
      this.array = this.array.map( (el, idx, arr) => arr[arr.length - idx - 1]);
      return this;
    }

    concatRight (...piramides : Array<Piramide>) : Piramide {
      return new Piramide({
        array : this.array.map( (el, i)=> el.concat(...piramides.filter(this.isConcatenable.bind(this)).map( pir => pir.getArray()[i] ) ) ),
        blanco : this.blanco, 
        trozo : this.trozo
      });     
    }

    concatLeft (...piramides : Array<Piramide>) : Piramide {
      return new Piramide({
        array :  this.array.map( (el, i)=> [].concat(...piramides.filter(this.isConcatenable.bind(this)).map( pir => pir.getArray()[i] ) ) ).map( (el, i)=> el.concat(this.array[i])),
        blanco : this.blanco, 
        trozo : this.trozo
      });     
    }

    concatAbove(...piramides : Array<Piramide>) {
      return new Piramide({
        array : piramides.reduce( (arr, pir) => arr.concat(pir.getArray()) , []).concat(this.array),
        blanco : this.blanco, 
        trozo : this.trozo
      });     
    }

    concatBelow(...piramides : Array<Piramide>) {
      return new Piramide({
        array : this.array.concat(piramides.reduce( (arr, pir) => arr.concat(pir.getArray()) , [])),
        blanco : this.blanco, 
        trozo : this.trozo
      });     
    }

}
```

It works, but it seems to me that this could be improved (I feel weird with my constructor and static methods).

Could this code be improved?

Answer (score 2):

When writing a simple function to return something if something is true or return something else, you should probably only have one return statement in the function.

increasing the amount of returns in a function makes the function less readable and more prone to mistakes.  if you only need one return statement, then only use one return statement.

Personally I would write this

> ```
> public getBlanco(){
>   if(this.array.length){
>     return this.array[1][0];
>   }
>   return null;
> }
> ```

like this instead

```
public getBlanco(){
    return this.array.length ? this.array[1][0] : null;
}
```

using a ternary is really the cleaner way to do this because you are really saying

```
if there are items in the array
    return item [1][0]
else
    return null
```